# handling error from Angular httpClient retryWhen block

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, httpclient, angular5

I have a pretty simple http call happening.  Upon error I want the request to retry 3 times with a three second delay between retries. I have worked out a solution that is close:

```
return this.http.put<string>(URL,
               value).retryWhen(err => {
                    return err
                    .delay(3000)
                    .take(3)
                    .concat(Observable.throw("error occurred"));
                })
               .catch(err => this.handleHttpError(err)) ;
```

The client retries three times like I expect.  However, I don't know how to throw the final error in such a way that my error handler (which normally expects an HttpResponse argument) can process the error.

Once I have taken(3) how can I get the final error, and convert it to an HttpResponse to send to my handler?  Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

I need to know, at the end of the day, the HttpResponse that accompanied the error(s).  When I throw the err from the retryWhen at the concat function that doesn't seem to accomplish it.

I am betting this is a pretty common thing to do, but being newer to Angular 5 and react I think I am just missing the boat.

Comment: Aren't you doing this already with `.catch(err => this.handleHttpError(err))`? Or what this method returns?

Comment: hmm. Well loosely. I catch the error, but I can't figure out how to throw an HttpResponse from the err Observable that is given to the retryWhen() .. what is thrown is an observable of err I believe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this, I was able to capture the httpErrorResponse by slightly changing the return:

first I added a local var

```
let httpError: HttpErrorResponse = null;
```

then I modified the return:

```
 return error
          .do(err => {if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {httpError = err; }})
          .delay(3000)
         .take(5)
         .concat(Observable.throw(error));
      })
```

this allows me to cache the last http error response.  I then look for this  in the catch and work accordingly. Seems to be working just fine.

Comment: I am having the same issue, are you still using this method? I tried it but I get an error for .do function (says not available)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `concatMap` to count how many times you've tried to resubscribe and according to that send `next` or `error` notifications (this means re-throwing the error in the inner observable that is propagated further).

```
Observable.throw(42)
  .retryWhen(err => err
    .do(console.info) // remove, prints 42
    .delay(3000)
    .concatMap((error, index) => {
      if (index === 2) {
        return Observable.throw("error occurred"); // or Observable.throw(error);
      }
      return Observable.of(null);
    })
  )
  // .catch(err => handleHttpError(err))
  .subscribe(
    v => console.log('next', v), // not called
    e => console.log('error handler', e),
  );
```

This prints the following output:

```
42
42
42
error handler: error occurred
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-jt5ald

Comment: the subscription is handled in a different part of the Angular app and it is functioning correctly.  The issue that I have is getting the httpResponse object that accompanied the error after the retry. I can't seem to find a way to do that from the err observable that is sent to the retryWhen from the httpClient. Does that make better sense?

Comment: So you want to send the error from `retryWhen` as `next` or `error` notification?